# I've flagged a comment as obsolete by mistake - what to do?

Tags: discussion, flags

I've recently flagged [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225411/boosts-linear-algebra-solution-for-y-ax#comment38270850_1297730):

> If all you need is a solution for Ax=y, just use `permutation_matrix<size_t> pm(A.size1()); lu_factorize(A, pm); lu_substitute(A, pm, y);` and `y` is replaced with the solution. –  [Joey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73070/joey)

under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1297730/2642204) as obsolete. At first sight it looks obsolete, as it contains the same sequence of function calls. However, during a code review, my coworker explained to me, that this in fact carries an important idea: solving "Ax=y" without calculating matrix inversion. So despite looking as completely redundant, it shows a very different idea than in the answer. I somehow assumed that it was incorporated to the answer by the author later (until I've noticed there were no edits...).

What can I do to inform the moderator about this, just in case they would've went by the same reasoning and remove this important comment?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not really anything you can do. You'll just have to trust that the Moderator that handles that flag will see that it is a mistake and will decline it. See also: [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/262755)

Comment: If the comment is deleted, you could re-post the comment or edit it into the answer, with attribution.

Comment: Well, it is still there. You can check your flag results from your Profile. I've "upvoted" the comment to try to help if the flag is still outstanding. I'm trusting your colleague on this :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've dismissed the flag.

Bringing it to meta or a chat room where mods are present is the best bet here. "Obsolete" comment flags tend to get processed by deleting the comment.

We can get comments back if they are deleted by mistake, but we're not likely to spend a lot of time doing so.